# AngularJS redirecting to another ng-app module

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, route-provider

newbie to AngularJS here.

I created one AngularJS application using Yeoman, grunt and bower.

The index page contains some style and ng-app and ng-view.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <!-- CSS Imports -->
   </head>
   <body ng-app="MyApp1">
      <div>
          //Some divs here to  have some styles

          <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </body>
    <!--importing AgularJS, app.js, controller JS files -->
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp1', [])
  .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
          redirectTo: '/main'
        })
      .when('/invoice', {
        templateUrl: 'views/invoice.html',
        controller: 'UploadController'
      })
      .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
          })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/main'
      });
//    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });

    angular.module('LoginApp', [])
    .config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    });
```

The index page has `ng-view` that will display invoice.html or main.html. Default is `main.html`. 
**main.html**

```
<div class="hero-unit">
  <a ng-href="views/login.html" target="_self">Login</a>
  <br>
  <a ng-href="#invoice">New Document</a>

</div>
```

Ok. In this `main.html`, I have two links. Second is a link to invoice. That anyway will display inside **index.html** `ng-view`. The controller `UploadController` belongs to **MyApp1** module. And it has separate JS file. It is working fine.

The first link is to another **HTML** page. Its **login.html**. It has another `ng-app` called **LoginApp**. Both the modules are independent and in diferent pages.

When I click on the first link, it goes to **login.html**. But in the URL it shows like `http://localhost:9000/views/login.html`. But I want it to be shown like `http://localhost:9000/login`, just like for other main.html (`http://localhost:9000/#/main`). When I edited the link like  `<a ng-href="#login">Login</a>` it is not working.

And also `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` is not working for me.

Comment: just changing `ng-href="views/login.html"` to `ng-href="/login"` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the login.html to same folder like index.html.

I think it's not possible to route to another module. However this route rule for login.html will not working for (external) page.

Comment: DO you know any other way?

Comment: Put the login.html to same folder like index.html and let the externely link <a ng-href="/login.html" target="_self">Login</a>

Comment: Still the URL doesn't change

Comment: Hi How can I add routing rule in second module?

When I add the `.when('/loginr', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
       }); `inside LoginApp module,
I am getting `Uncaught Error: No module: LoginApp`

Comment: mc: no routing rule, only <a href="login.html" target="_self">Login</a>